# django-concurrency is doing nothing

Tags: django, concurrency

I am testing my app for concurrency 
I am using django-concurrency

For every model added

```
from concurrency.fields import IntegerVersionField

version = IntegerVersionField( )
```

So i open with 2 browser windows my app. log with 2 different users and the edit with both same record . Save with one then I save with second one and always second one just overwrites the first one . Basically does nothing . 
Expected to get an error on my second save.

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used Django concurrency and I would run a mile if I run across apps that offer to abstract concurrency, transaction management etc. Based on general concepts of concurrency. This behaviour seems right. There's no error here.

> django-concurrency is an optimistic lock [1] implementation for
>   Django.
>
> Supported Django versions: 1.8.x, 1.9.x, 1.10.x., 1.11.x
>
> It prevents users from doing concurrent editing in Django both from UI
>   and from a django command.

What this actually means is that two users cannot modify the same instance at the same time. In adhoc two browser testing of the sort that's just tried out, such a situation can never be produced! What usually happens is that one or the other transaction usually runs to completion because when testing on small databases on localhost, there is no latency and everything happens instantly.

The proper way to test this is to open up to separate change shells, open up the same instance and edit as outlined in the django concurrency guide. Or test with a multi threaded client.

Comment: thanks, I assumed it will create a new version id when I save and when I save again it will check that version Id is different then one it currently has and will give an error on 2nd saving...

If it is just solves situation of same moment  saving it is not that useful.

Comment: yes, it's probably better to handle transactions manually instead of by a black box